# What does the word "being" mean?

Tags: word-meaning, american-english, present-participles

I'm from Russia, and of course my native language is Russian. But I read a lot of English books. Periodically I come across the word "being". I think it's "be" + "ing", but don't fully understand it. I know that it's used in the Bible, and it meant all around what exists, time + space. But what does this word mean in ordinary life?

For example, here is a sentence I found this word:

> This makes constructing entities easier, and it also allows the developer to define a set of entities that are interesting for the game **that’s being developed**.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is the present participle of 'to be'. Just like doing, running, crying, living etc it means 'in the process of'.

'He was being helpful', means ' he was in the process of helping'.

Answer (score 1):

Ditto WS2.

Let me add that "being" as a noun means "a thing that exists", and is used when the context requires you to be very vague and general. Like you might refer to an alien life form as "an intelligent being". You don't want to call it human because it's not biologically human. You don't want to call it a person because that could be understood to mean human. But you don't want to call it an animal because that might imply lack of intelligence. Etc.

I don't recall the word being used in the Bible in the sense you describe, but there are many translations out there. You could say, for example, "All being and all creation were made by God" or something of that sort, it's not implausible.